# What launches an ancient "Update Helper" and how do I confirm it's not a trojan?

Tags: macos, security, auto-update

Once in a while a program nags me out of the blue to update. I seldom yield since I always suspect a trojan. For example today I get a persistent:

[image: Google Earth Update Helper wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this.]

I launch `Activity Monitor` and sure enough, there is indeed a process with that name.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Yet after the last upgrade (to El Capitan) I didn't bother installing either Google Chrome or Google Earth. I confirm this in my `/Applications` folder.

But I do see the folder `~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin`, presumably left from a previous installation. I am puzzled. After looking at my login tasks

[image: Login tasks]

I see that Google Earth should not be running at login.

What launched it, and, more importantly, how do I confirm that such a request from an "`Update Helper`" is not a trojan?

**Update**

The answers and comments indicate that what I was asking is not clear. There are four questions/problems that need to be solved in this context. In order of increasing difficulty they are:

1. I no longer use Chrome or Earth. How do I remove the Google Software Updater.
2. How do I remove any one particular software updater if I no longer use, nor have installed since the last major OS X upgrade, that software?
3. Some random window pops up and asks me to enter my password. It's bad enough if my user files are contaminated, but it's a completely different problem if I give a suspect program superuser privileges and take a chance in contaminating the system. How do I confirm which piece of software is popping the window? (And how could something be running without being present in the login tasks? I don't see any root cron jobs. Where else should I be looking?)
4. There is a problem with OS X major release upgrades. I upgrade in-place (i.e., without formatting my drive). Both ~/Library and /Library are swelling
   (`sudo du -h -s /Library` reports 3.5G and `sudo du -h -s ~/Library` reports 4.7G). How do I purge the unnecessary folders?

I meant to ask Q3, but I'll gladly settle for an answer to Q1.

In your answers and comments several people have recommended that [this discussion](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/) will solve Q1. While that article is indeed very helpful, I don't have the file

```
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/\
Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py
```

The nearest file I have is

```
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/\
Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall
```

I'm tempted to just wipe out the folder

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Not installing Google Earth after the last update is really not the same thing as having thoroughly uninstalled it. See http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/ as there's too much to precis here.

Comment: This may not be a final solution but as per the article mentioned, running `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
` should at the very least disable the updater until a solution is found to remove it completely.

Comment: If you read the discussion completely you will find in the comments section one person wrote that the `install.py` file has been replaced with `ksinstall`.

Comment: @user556068 You're absolutely right. I've run this line and 0 seems to be behaving indeed as 'never'. Still, it would be nice to take this chance and get rid of the files leftover by Chrome/Earth in ~/Library.

Comment: @user556068  Thanks. I had skipped the comments. I'm happy to report that running  `~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --uninstall` does indeed purge the subtree rooted at `~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/`. Afterwards running `defaults read com.google.Keystone.Agent` replies with `Domain com.google.Keystone.Agent does not exist`. All is well. Would you care to summarize an answer for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, [this discussion](http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/) has some good tips for accomplishing this.

**I have not tested any of these solutions as I still frequently use Google Chrome and do not want to delete these files myself.**

If your Library contains a `install.py` file:

`python
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall`

or:

`python
/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall`

If your Library instead contains a `ksinstall` file:

`~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Google‌​SoftwareUpdate.bundl‌​e/Contents/R‌​esources/GoogleS‌​oftwareUpdateAgent.a‌​pp/Contents/‌​Resources/ksinst‌​all --uninstall`

or:

`/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Google‌​SoftwareUpdate.bundl‌​e/Contents/R‌​esources/GoogleS‌​oftwareUpdateAgent.a‌​pp/Contents/‌​Resources/ksinst‌​all --uninstall`

Test if it worked by running `defaults read com.google.Keystone.Agent`. If it worked you should see `Domain com.google.Keystone.Agent does not exist`.

Alternatively you can also **disable** the updater without removing it completely by running:

`defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`. The `0` essentially tells the updater to never check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Check this link out. It uses Terminal to stop the auto updating that is coming directly from Google!  I did this about an hour or so ago and the updater never came back. This is for Mac, though!

http://applehelpwriter.com/2014/07/13/how-to-remove-googles-secret-update-software-from-your-mac/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While the link you provided is a good resource, it's better to post the relevant parts as part of your answer since links often times go stale making your answer unusable.

Answer (score -2):

I just had the same thing start happening. Just found this:

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1325327

May help explain. Seems it's a Google update error?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.